# Tag "points" went down even though reputation is higher

Tags: support, tags, reputation, tag-score

Here is a screenshot of my Stack Overflow profile from January 2020.

[image]

Now here's my profile from today.

[image]

My reputation has gone up quite a bit (from 21750 to 29489). **Can someone explain why "score" for the two tags `machine-learning` and `python` have both gone down substantially?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Some of the questions you answered have their [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tags removed**.

The displayed score on the profile is **the total score of the non-wiki answers**.

At least 2 questions were retagged quite recently:

- [What are logits? What is the difference between softmax and softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240703/what-are-logits-what-is-the-difference-between-softmax-and-softmax-cross-entrop) ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tags removed, reducing 305 from the score)
- [Find percentile stats of a given column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581893/find-percentile-stats-of-a-given-column) ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag removed, reducing 97 from the score)

Comment: Thank you for the detective work. The people removing those tags don't know what they're doing.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Well you _are_ able to roll the edits back if you think they're that bad. Just saying they don't know what they're is useless, if you're not happy do something about it.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I don't know anything about TensorFlow but its usage guidance says _"Use this tag with a language-specific tag ([python], [c++], [javascript], [r], etc.) for questions about using the API to solve machine learning problems."_  As to the second question, [pandas] is a Python library and I see it used with [python] all the time. Neither of those is my area of expertise though, so you decide whether the questions need to be retagged.

Comment: It's just really frustrating to have posts about `machine-learning` be edited by users whose own main tags are `javascript` and `debian-packaging`.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 stop adding tags willy nilly. Statistics has nothing to do with that question, so python-2.x. And despite my main tags being debian packaging is by choice because otherwise I have to deal with questions like the ones you answer.

Comment: @Braiam: Please stop editing questions you know nothing about. Just stick to `javascript`. You removed the tags `machine-learning` and `python` from this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240703/what-are-logits-what-is-the-difference-between-softmax-and-softmax-cross-entrop . Do you even know that that question is about?

Comment: @Braiam: I'm still waiting for your answer. Do you even know what that question is about?